# Power of the axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider the different uses below

1. ”A person comes into a bar… ” – which I take to be a description of a joke which can be told without knowing the person’s actual name. 
   This is as contrast to
2. A story about Obama, which might require the name to be presented.

I now wonder in a similar intuitive way (please take my ignorance into account) what mandate I get from using the axiom of choice.

Does it give me the right only to choose a number without actually knowing the value of the number, as in alternative 1, or does it, as in alternative 2. give me access to an expansion in a base, i.e. an infinite series which is available to me even if it requires an infinite instruction (and cannot be given in a finite form)?

Edit: I take my comment below as my edit to try to comply with the site´s rules for clarity:

@Mosher To rephrase my question to fit your function: Do you know, from the AC, only that such a function exist, or does the AC allow you to choose a particular case of this function - or do you perhaps consider these alternatives to be one and the same?

I see it as saying that a real number exist that you don´t know vs. allowing you to choose a particular number (in the form of a particular form of an infinite set) – or whether this is the same thing in your opinion?

Comment: Can you be more specific. (1) and (2) have nothing to do with the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom of choice is not about choosing a single element: if you know that the population of the bar is nonempty, you may choose an element without using the axiom of choice.

Instead, the mandate you get from the axiom of choice is the ability to choose a whole function's worth of elements. If you have a function $F$ defined on a set $I$ such that $F(i)$ is a nonempty set for each $i \in I$, then the axiom of choice tells you that there is a function $f$ defined on the same set $I$ such that $f(i) \in F(i)$ for all $i \in I$.

Comment: @Mosher To rephrase my question to fit your function: Do you know, from the AC, only that such a function exist –or does the AC allow you to choose a particular case of this function   - or do you perhaps consider these alternatives to be one and the same? 
I see it as saying that a real number exist that you don´t know vs. allowing you to choose a particular number (in the form of a particular form of an infinite set) – or whether this is the same thing in your opinion.

Comment: This is not a philosophical or opinion based issue. This is an issue of how logic is used in mathematics. The basic principle of logic is something which I have heard called "choose it then use it", and it goes like this. Suppose you know have a statement of the following form which you know is true: "There exists $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true". Then, you may choose an element $x$, assume that $P(x)$ is true, and use the truth of $P(x)$ in your subsequent argument.

Comment: I am at the moment more interested in the chosen x but I take it that you consider that I can choose an actual value x.